# PHP replace string with value from array

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace words in a string with words from an array. Problem is the result repeated multiple times. I know there is a gotcha for `str_replace`, but i can't find any solution for this problem.

I tried with `str_replace` and `preg_replace`.

#### My codes:

With `str_replace`:

```
$text = 'Amir and Mahdi are friends.';
$text2 = str_replace(array("Amir","Mahdi"), '{Amir|Mahdi}', $text);
```

Result: `{Amir|{Amir|Mahdi}} and {Amir|Mahdi} are friends.`

---

With `preg_replace`:

```
$text = 'Amir and Mahdi are friends.';
$text2 = preg_replace(array("/Amir/","/Mahdi/"), '{Amir|Mahdi}', $text);
```

Result: `{Amir|{Amir|Mahdi}} and {Amir|Mahdi} are friends.`

---

I want this result: `{Amir|Mahdi} and {Amir|Mahdi} are friends.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with replace patter as array it first converts `{Amir|Mahdi} and Mahdi are friends.`, again for arrays second index `Mahdi` it converts both `Mahdi`. That's why I suggest you to use `|` ([**OR**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) condition in pattern instead of array.

```
$text = 'Amir and Mahdi are friends.';
$text2 = preg_replace("/Amir|Mahdi/", '{Amir|Mahdi}', $text);
echo $text2;
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/RTn8E).